# Windows Emacs : copy/edit files from/to remote UNIX machine?

Tags: emacs

Windows 7 (64 bit)
Emacs 24.5

To explore local files (on Windows) I use package **dired+**. OK.

1. How I can see (by dired+) files on remote UNIX machine?
2. How I can edit/copy files (by dered+) from/to remote UNIX machine?

If not use Emacs, I connect to remote UNIX machine by windows console with next command:

ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no login@ip.of.unix.machine

In emacs:
Try connect from Windows 7 to Unix:

/ssh:root@1.2.3.4:

Error:
ssh -1 root -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none 1.2.3.4 && exit || exit

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Could not create directory '/home/Alex/.ssh'.

ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/sbin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed

Comment: HI, use Tramp ! http://wikemacs.org/wiki/TRAMP

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution to this - you need the env variable `SSH_ASKPASS` pointing to `git-gui--askpass`. It is located in the git installation directory, in my case

```
(setenv SSH_ASKPASS "...Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui--askpass")
```

Comment: I use Tramp mode and it's work OK. I can copy/move files from/to remote Linux machine.

Comment: I am using `emacs 26.3` under `Windows 10` without `mingw64`. Fortunately, I have installed `Git` and the proposed solution works fine for me too. @RecencyEffect you made my day, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use Tramp.  See the Emacs manual, node [Remote Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Remote-Files.html).

In Dired, including [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), just use the remote-file syntax for the remote directory that you want to open in Dired mode.